# Xamarin Facebook GraphRequest Deadlock

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin.ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

I tried to load some information from a Facebook user but it seems like I am getting a Deadlock calling this code. What could be wrong?

```
public Task<Page<T>> LoadGraphRequest<T>(User user, string edge, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Page<T>>();
        //NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(parameters.Values.ToArray(), parameters.Keys.ToArray())
        var request = new GraphRequest($"{user.FacebookID}/{edge}", null);

        request.Start((connection, result, error) =>
        {
            //Callback never called
            try
            {
                if (error == null && result != null)
                {
                    //load Page<T> from Result
                    //tcs.SetResult(page);
                }
                else {
                    tcs.SetResult(null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"GraphRequest Error: {ex.Message}");
                tcs.SetResult(null);
            }
        });

        return tcs.Task;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code is working.
I think it was due to some compilation errors.
I deleted Bin and Obj folders.